# add code blocks to end of body and inside head from template in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have used Django and in Django template engine we define blocks like

```
<head>
    {% block head %} {% endblock head %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
    .....
    {% block script %} {% endblock script %}
</body>
</html>
```

in each template file extending this layout we include codes in particular blocks to put in `head`, `body`, `script` respectively.

Now, I'm using **`CakePHP`** and want to achieve the same as I have lot of `js` files at the end of body tag and include `script` below them which are particularly for each page. Means, that script will be called from particular page only and thus I can't put it on all pages.

The layout of CakePHP looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- all head elements -->
</head>
<body>
    <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>

    <!-- all js includes -->
</body>
</html>
```

**How to add script at the end of body tag in CakePHP 3?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in the manual [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files)

In your view file

```
<?php
    $this->Html->script('yourjavascriptfile', ['block' => 'scriptBottom']);
?>
```

then in your layout

```
<body>
    <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('scriptBottom') ?>
</body>
```